# ASP.NET - Load HTML page in Master Page

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm a newbie with asp.net but not with C# and I was wondering if any know how I can achieve the following:

I wish to create a ASP.NET website with a master page; but load up a HTML page as a Content Page. I want to do this because I want to use these really nice HTML charts (as opposed to the crappy ASP.NET charts) and serve these charts up when the page is selected.

NOTE: I am using ASP.NET (not MVC)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is an   asp.net question, not a classic asp question.  You can use client side HTML and Javascript in an .aspx page, it shouldn't interfere with your server side asp.net code

Comment: Hi. Yes, but I want to load it in the same manner as the Master Page does with Content .aspx pages. That is; in a frame-like manner.

Comment: There's nothing "frame like" about master pages, the .master and the .aspx are combined server side and the browser sees them as a single html page.  You could put a javascript function in the head section of your master page and call it from your content page and it would be executed by the browser client side.  Can you give a example, in flat html if you like, of what exactly you want to do